# Command 'time' works on its own but not in a pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, time

Consider the following:

```
# time sleep 1

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
# echo foo | time sleep 1
bash: time: command not found
```

Um... wut?

OK, so *clearly* Bash is searching for commands in a somehow different way when run as a pipeline. Can anyone explain to me what the difference is? Does piping disable shell built-ins or something? (I didn't think it did... but... I can't see how else this is breaking.)

Comment: @Kusalananda `time` is usually a shell built-in *and* an external program. Although on this system, the external command isn't installed for some reason. Also: I specifically want to time *one part* of the pipeline, not the entire thing.

Comment: `time` is not a shell built-in, but a keyword. See also [How can we make \`time\` apply to a pipeline or its component?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444509)

Comment: @Kusalananda point is that `time command` runs the shell keyword, but `echo foo | time command` runs the binary. I can reproduce this on my Arch Linux system. And that is indeed surprising.

Comment: @terdon It's not surprising. The keyword `time` is only allowed in certain places in the grammar. In particular, it's part of the syntax for a pipeline. It's specifically allowed at the start of a pipeline: `[time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ | command2 … ]`.  Using `time` _at any other place_ would call the external utility.  If there isn't one, then you get the obvious error message from the shell.

Comment: Please note that "time one part of the pipeline" might not be doing what you want – all the commands of a pipeline might be running in parallel.

Comment: and [POSIX leaves `time` in pipelines unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/time.html) (stuff like `time a | b | c` and `a | b | time c`), likely exactly because some shells have it as a keyword that times the full pipeline, and some don't. "When _time_ is used as part of a pipeline, the times reported are unspecified, except when it is the sole command within a grouping command"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `bash` shell implements `time` as a keyword.  The keyword is part of syntax of the pipeline.

The syntax of a pipeline in `bash` is (from the section entitled "[Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines)" in the `bash` manual):

> ```bsh
> [time [-p]] [!] command1 [ | or |& command2 ] …
> ```

Since `time` is part of the *syntax of pipelines*, not a shell built-in utility, it does not behave as a utility.  For example, redirecting its output using ordinary shell redirections is not possible without extra trickery (see e.g. [How can I redirect `time` output and command output to the same pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115980)).

When the word `time` occurs in any other place than at the start of a pipeline in the `bash` shell, the external command with the same name will be called.  This is what happens in the case when you put `time` after the pipe symbol, for example.  If the shell can't find an external `time` command, it generates a "command not found" error.

To make the shell use the keyword to time only the `sleep 1` command in your pipeline, you may use

```bsh
echo foo | (time sleep 1)
```

Within the subshell on the right hand side of the pipeline, the `time` keyword is at the start of a pipeline (a pipeline of a single simple command, but still).

Also related:

- [How can we make `time` apply to a pipeline or its component?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444509)
- [Bash time keyword result only with second piped command, explain why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402032)
- [Make bash use external `time` command rather than shell built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266)
- [Differences between keyword, reserved word, and builtin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267761)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `/usr/bin/time` which can give you more details too:

```
echo foo | /usr/bin/time sleep 1
```

Comment: Actually, this is what Bash was trying to do in the first place; the problem was `/usr/bin/time` doesn't exist on this particular system.